# .scrollTop and .load Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div:

```
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

And I  load data into it with ajax, however using this technique .scrollTop doesnt seem to work. Perhaps the program thinks there isnt anyhting "physical" in it if you understand what im trying to say, just something JavaScript has put in. How can I make it work?

Code:

```
<div id="conversation" name="conversation" style="height:400px;overflow:scroll;margin-top: 25px;"></div>
```

....

```
function loadConversation(){
   $("#conversation").load("../includes/ajax/getConversation.php?offset=0&memberid=1911&maxoffset=20");
   $('#conversation').scrollTop = 9999;
 }

 loadConversation();
 setInterval (loadConversation, 2500);
```

Comment: Please post your code - it should work normally

Comment: you will need to show us how you use `scrollTop` and what you expect to happen. And what happens that seems wrong..

Comment: code added to above post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always believe scrollTop was a function not a property. Why don't you try like this.

```
  $("#conversation").load("../includes/ajax/getConversation.php?offset=0&memberid=1911&maxoffset=20", function() {
     $('#conversation').scrollTop(9999);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's load function is asynchronous, so when you call scrollTop, there is still nothing there.

To do what you want, you need to use a callback to call scrollTop after the content is added.

Try this:

```
$("#conversation").load("../includes/ajax/getConversation.php?offset=0&memberid=1911&maxoffset=20", function() {
    $('#conversation').scrollTop = 9999;
});
```

Comment: thanks but even injecting my browser with javascript:$('#conversation').scrollTop = 9999; doesnt make it do whats its supposed too.. strange

Comment: Actually I think maxjib got this one right, I wasn't paying attention, but scrollTop is a function.